# Как улучшить качество отображаемого фото в moodle?

Tags: html, css, moodle

В moodle сделали через код отображение фото пользователя прямоугольным, а качество отображение плохое. Как это можно исправить? Или это где-то в коде сжимается качество отображения?

```css
.pagelayout-mypublic .card-profile .userpicture img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #ac3431;
    border-radius: 0%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]